# CSS Grid - In this grid, why is one row resp. item too big?

Tags: css, css-grid

Consider the following example:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  background-color: red;
}

.item2 {
  grid-row: 2/4;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  background-color: lime;
}

.content1 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.content2 {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item1">
        <div class="content1">
    Content 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <div class="content2">
    Content 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/px9rcL2j/)

Can you explain to me, why in the result `.item2` is 85px high? I expected `.content2` to set the height (70px) for its parent grid item `.item2`. Where do the other 15px come from?

It looks like the last row has some kind of height setting, so it forces `.item2` to take up that space?

Also if I change the height of `.content1` this has influence on the height of `.item2` resp. the height of the last row. Can you tell me how this is connected?

How do I express it in a way, that `content2` actually defines the height for `.item2` and therefore defines the height of the last row? I.e. what I want is that the green area is not visible and the grid ends with the end of `.content2`

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: what's important to me is to not only make the item smaller by using `fit-content`, but I want the whole last row (and therefore the whole grid) to be smaller, such that it exactly covers `content2`. I'm trying to understand why that last row has that height is has.

Comment: change `auto` with `fr`

Comment: Use `height: fit-content;` on both parent grid items `.item1` and `.item2`. See my answer for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last row contains extra height because of the fact that CSS computes the total height for your grid as follows:

Item1 is spanning for 100px, over row 1 and 2.

Next up, we have item2, which is spanning here 70px, over row 2 and 3.

Now getting to the main part, to compute the row-height, css takes a look at the first available element, checks out the proportion and calculates the row height.

**For row-1:**
Since content1 from item1 has a height of 100px, and spans equally over 2 rows, we have:
Row-1 height = 100/2 = 50px

**For row-2:**
Since the first element, item1 has a height of 100px, and spans equally over 2 rows, we have:
Row-2 height = 100/2 = 50px
item1 comes before item2 in precedence, hence the height of item2 is ignored.

**For row-3:**
Since the first and only element in row 3, content2 from item2 has a height of 70px, and spans equally over 2 rows, we have:
Row-3 height = 70/2 = 35px

Hence, your grid's total height comes off as 50+50+35 = 145px.

Ideally, item2 would've been spanning equally over the last two rows, 35px height each.
But since the height for row-2 has been defined as 50px, 50px of content2 is filled in row 2 itself, and hence only 20px of height from content2 remains to be added in row-3.

However, since the height for item3 is defined as the sum of heights of row-2 +  row-3, which is 50px + 35px = 85px.

Hence the surplus space = 85px - 70px.

If you give me a few minutes, I can work out a js workaround solution for this, so let me know if I should do that. Hope you found this insightful, this is my first answer on StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! This explanation was exactly what I needed. Thanks for offering your help on a js workaround, but I think I can do that myself, now that I understand what's going on. Just one thing: Do you have any resources/articles that further describe those calculation steps? It's the first time I'm hearing of this.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of some help! I just thought hard on why would that be happening, and scribbled these calculations, however, after some digging, I feel you would find what you're looking for in the official CSS module here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/CRD-css-grid-1-20201218/
at 6.6 - Automatic Minimum Size of Grid Items

Answer (score -1):

Just add `height: fit-content;` to both parent grid elements `.item1` and `.item2`. Grid items do not inherently take the `height` of their content. By default, they inherit their `height` value from the computed height of the grid rows they take up.

This change, and setting the height of your rows to use `fr` units instead of `auto` does the trick. Just make sure to only set the exact rows you'll be using. In this case, I changed your row count within the `repeat()` from `3` to `2` and switched `auto` to `1fr`. Without this, there is no property to set a max-height of a row to fit its content. But if a row height isn't explicitly set, it will only take up the minimum height required to fit the content.

Here it is applied to your example, with only those two instances of `height: fit-content;` added:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  background-color: red;
  height: fit-content;
}

.item2 {
  grid-row: 2/4;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  background-color: lime;
  height: fit-content;
}

.content1 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.content2 {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item1">
        <div class="content1">
    Content 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <div class="content2">
    Content 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still isn't exactly what I wanted. I want the whole grid to end at the bottom line of Content2. So the last row should be smaller. My core question is: why does the last row have that additional height?

Comment: @Raphael I've adjusted my answer to account for this change as well. For future reference, it's not good practice to downvote an answer for something you didn't clarify first in your question. Not sure if that was you, but I adjusted my answer to fit your new requirements which you have since updated in your post. Please give those answering your question the time needed to adjust to new requirements, especially given that my original solution did meet your original requirements. Thank you.

Comment: @Raphael if you are looking for a CSS-only way of overriding a grid-row's height to fit that row's content, I don't believe that is possible, but it will work for non-set grid rows as I explained above and demonstrated in my solution. If you need to cap the entire grid at the end of its content, this is possible with some minor JS. This is not a bug in CSS but actually a feature that allows us to set the height of the grid cells in relation to their parent. Otherwise, setting a grid item's height to `50%` wouldn't work.